# Recursively duplicating entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am attempting to duplicate an entry. That part isn't hard. The tricky part is: there are `n` entries connected with a foreign key. And for each of those entries, there are `n` entries connected to that. I did it manually using a lookup to duplicate and cross reference the foreign keys.
Is there some subroutine or method to duplicate an entry and search for and duplicate foreign entries? Perhaps there is a name for this type of replication I haven't stumbled on yet, is there a specific database related title for this type of operation?

`PostgreSQL 8.4.13`

`main` entry (uid is serial)

```
 uid | title   
-----+-------
   1 | stuff
```

`department` (departmentid is serial, uidref is foreign key for uid above)

```
 departmentid | uidref | title         
--------------+--------+-------
          100 |      1 | Foo
          101 |      1 | Bar
```

`sub_category` of department (textid is serial, departmentref is foreign for departmentid above)

```
textid | departmentref | title          
-------+---------------+----------------
  1000 |           100 | Text for Foo 1 
  1001 |           100 | Text for Foo 2 
  1002 |           101 | Text for Bar 1
```

Comment: Table definitions would be groovy (primary key? serial? foreign keys?). And your Postgres version. And the query you used for doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in a single statement using [**data-modifying CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (requires Postgres **9.1** or later).
Your primary keys being `serial` columns makes it easier:

```
WITH m AS (
   INSERT INTO main (<all columns except pk>)
   SELECT <all columns except pk>
   FROM   main
   WHERE  uid = 1
   RETURNING uid AS uidref                  -- returns new uid
   )
, d AS (
   INSERT INTO department (<all columns except pk>)
   SELECT <all columns except pk>
   FROM   m
   JOIN   department d USING (uidref)
   RETURNING departmentid AS departmentref  -- returns new departmentids
   )
INSERT INTO sub_category (<all columns except pk>)
SELECT <all columns except pk>
FROM   d
JOIN   sub_category s USING (departmentref);
```

Replace `<all columns except pk>` with your actual columns. `pk` is for `primary key`, like `main.uid`.

The query returns nothing. You *can* return pretty much anything. You just didn't specify anything.

You wouldn't call that "replication". That term usually is applied for keeping multiple database instances or objects in sync. You are just duplicating an entry - and depending objects recursively.

Aside about naming conventions:
It would get even simpler with a naming convention that labels *all* columns signifying "ID of table foo" with the *same* (descriptive) name, like `foo_id`. There are other naming conventions floating around, but this is the best for writing queries, IMO.

Comment: ok, I gotta pore over this. it seems pk is a reserved keyword, and the last part is the query that retrieves the data to be duplicated? sadly I am on 8.4.13 (editing OP)

Comment: @roberthuttinger: I added some explanation. Follow the link to the manual for details. And there are lots of examples and explanation here on SO.

Comment: got it, the <> convention is a note of what to do...<palm/face>

Comment: I tried searching yesterday and today, and didnt find anything that fit. so I asked the question today. Im still looking.. thanks!!

Comment: I see you just added `Postgres 8.4`. This won't work for you then. I *did* ask for your version of Postgres before and it should be obvious to provide that to begin with ... Either way, [Postgres 8.4 is on it's way out and will be unsupported this summer](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading to a current version.

Comment: when you posted it, I was literraly typing `select version()` into the CLI!